# Problemas al cambiar URL en Worddress

Tags: css, wordpress

Estoy tratando de cambiar la URL genérica de mi WordPress(la que me da el hosting por defecto) con dos dominios que acabo de comprar, y ninguno funciona.

He seguido los pasos para cambiar la URL a través del archivo wp.config.php poniendo este código justo delante de dónde me permite editar:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://yoursiteurl.com' );
    define( 'WP_SITEURL', ‘http://yoursiteurl.com' );
```

pero al hacerlo, la página no carga, o aparece con con muchos errores(no se ven las imagenes, sale solo texto pero desorganizado. Incluso me he comprado dos dominios (.com y .net) y con el .net aparecen la página toda hecha un caos, y el .com simplemente no carga.

He buscado mucho en google y no encuentro la solución a estos problemas con el cambio de URL.

No creo que puedan ser los DNS porque los he puesto bien en mi proveedor de dominios.

¿Qué podría hacer para que funcione el cambio de URL correctamente?

Answer (score 1):

Primero verifica que el dominio se haya asignado a tu host usando [whatsmydns](https://www.whatsmydns.net/) para verificar que los DNS se hayan propagado correctamente (La propagación de DNS suele llevar algo de tiempo, desde 20 minutos hasta 4 horas o incluso más).

Una vez hayas verificado que los DNS se propagaron y que el dominio ya esta en tu host entonces debes asignar el dominio en tu host como un dominio adicional, este proceso solo si tu host y tu dominio esta en proveedores diferentes.

Luego de la asignación ve a WordPress -> Ajustes Generales -> y cambia la dirección de WordPress y la dirección del sitio, guarda los ajustes y verifica que se haya hecho el cambio.

Si no puedes de esta forma intenta ingresar a phpMyAdmin, localiza la base de datos de tu sitio y busca la tabla wp_options, cambia desde ahí la url del sitio y de WordPress, recuerda usar el dominio como tal sin agregar la / al final, ya que esto provocaría un error.

Espero te ayude, suerte!

Comment: Hola, después de varios tickets mi proveedor de dominios me dijo esto: "Te indicamos que, por nuestra parte, los DNS están correctamente configurados en nuestros sistemas con lo que el error reside en el proveedor de dichos DNS.

De esta forma, deberás contactar con 000WebHost para que puedan revisar la correcta configuración de los DNS que te han facilitado y llevar a cabo cualquier acción a respecto."  Y en 000webhost me dicen que " La propagación del dominio toma un tiempo dependiendo del registrador". Yo pienso que el problema debe ser del proveedor de dominio y poreso no propaga DNS.